# OPC-UA in ROS 2 to communicate with PLC

Tags: ros, communication, ros2, plc

I would like to establish a communication between my PLC ([RevPi](https://revolutionpi.de/shop/en/revpi-connect)) which runs [Codesys](https://store.codesys.com/codesys-control-for-raspberry-pi-sl.html) and a Jetson Nano (or Rasperry Pi) which will be running ROS2. The latter will be connected to a Router (for uploading data to a server), as can be seen on the image below.

My question is therefore: Is it possible to use OPC UA in ROS 2 to transfer the data to my PLC?

Thank you for your answers!
[image: Hardware Setup]

Edit: I am aware of [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_opcua_communication) and [this solution](https://github.com/ScalABLE40/robin), but it doesn't seem to be compatible with ROS 2.

Comment: I have the same question regarding a project I am working on. Have you found anything in the meantime concerning the communication via OPC UA with ROS2?

Comment: I am working on it. Please send me a [message](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Max-Cichocki) and we can discuss in detail.

Comment: You can run one script that can gather or send the data from/to the PLC and then connect to the ROS node on rapsberry pi ? Note that you can run this script on Raspbery PI itself. If you are using Python , it has a cool opc-ua module .

Answer (score 1):

So to your direct question there is work to provide OPC-UA as a ROS 2 transport "inside" of ROS 2. See [these slides](https://rosindustrial.org/s/ROS-I-Conf2016-day1-09-keinert.pdf) form the [2016 ROS I conference](https://rosindustrial.org/events/2016/11/3/2016-ros-industrial-conference)

However, I think that the more practical approach will be not to try to run ROS 2 on your PLC, but to bridge it out with a standard OPC-UA client on the Jetson, and then republish it on the ROS 2 communications channel. This will keep things separate and not require you to try to merge two different communication protocols.

Alternatively you could also consider running a ROS 2 node on your PLC and then publishing it via ROS 2 messages to the Jetson as well. Which will require compiling onto the PLC but then just be one more network connection in ROS 2.

Comment: > Alternatively you could also consider running a ROS 2 node on your PLC.
How on Earth can you do that?